# Why doesn't svg work in bootstrap media object?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, svg, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have been trying to use svg in bootstrap media object and found that it doesn't take it's minimum width if width is not set explicitly. E.g. consider the simple case with a png image:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="media">
  <div class="media-left">
    <a href="#">
      <img class="media-object" src="https://www.tutorialspoint.com/bootstrap/images/64.jpg" alt="...">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="media-body">
    <h4 class="media-heading">Media heading</h4>
    sample text. This is some sample text. This is some sample text. This is some sample text. This is some s
  </div>
</div>
```

The png image used has default width of 64px so it shows as a 64px wide image. Now consider the same example with an svg img:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="media">
  <div class="media-left">
    <a href="#">
      <img class="media-object" src="http://www.iconninja.com/files/93/412/839/social-online-media-pay-paypay-pal-icon.svg" alt="...">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="media-body">
    <h4 class="media-heading">Media heading</h4>
    The random text that shows that the text that was suypposed to be the text.
  </div>
</div>
```

We can see that in second example the svg doesn't take it's minimum default width like a png or jpg does. On the other hand if I simply have two image tags in body tag and first image is png and second is svg and both images don't have width set explicitly then both the images take their default width.

My question is why does in bootstrap media object the svg take it's default width?

Answer (score 5):

Images (`gif/jpg/png`) are pixel-based, and by default they have `width/height` values, while SVG are vector objects, and the `width/height` depends on who/what is display them.

In your example - the SVG has viewBox of `32 x 32` (which defines the portion of the canvas to display).

You can read more about viewBox in the reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Positions

If you want to can define the `width` and `height` inside the `svg`:

```
<svg width="64" height="64"...> ... </svg>
```

Here is a working example (note that I used an inline svg here):

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="media">
  <div class="media-left">
    <a href="#">
      <img class="media-object" src='data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,
<?xml version="1.0" ?><svg width="64" height="64" enable-background="new 0 0 32 32" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 32 32" xml:space="preserve" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><g id="Flat_copy_7"><g><path d="M15.995,0c-8.837,0-16,7.163-16,16c0,8.836,7.163,16,16,16s16-7.164,16-16C31.995,7.163,24.831,0,15.995,0    z" fill="#E8E8E8"/></g><path d="M13.099,23.163l0.784-3.334c0,0,0.243-0.952,1.292-0.952c1.047,0,8.298,0.277,9.904-4.842   c0.589-1.871,0.997-6.31-6.324-6.31h-5.287c0,0-1.1-0.05-1.371,1.09L8.64,23.362c0,0-0.148,0.912,0.797,0.912   c0.946,0,2.36,0,2.36,0S12.886,24.333,13.099,23.163z M15.093,14.702l0.702-2.957c0,0,0.224-0.804,0.946-0.922   c0.722-0.12,1.951,0.02,2.268,0.079c2.054,0.376,1.617,2.272,1.617,2.272c-0.407,2.926-5.075,2.519-5.075,2.519   C14.818,15.435,15.093,14.702,15.093,14.702z" fill="#333333"/></g></svg>' alt="...">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="media-body">
    <h4 class="media-heading">Media heading</h4>
    The random text that shows that the text that was suypposed to be the text.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But if I have two images in body tag as: `<body><img src="example.png><img src="example.svg"></body>`. Now here I have not mentioned width and height attributes on any img tag but still they both take their minimum width. What is in bootstrap media object that displays it in such a way that svg don't take that minmum width?

Comment: The browser will display the image based on it's default width/height, or the width/height of the container in case of SVG that is `display: block` (which is your case). Since the container has no width - the svg-image will also have no width.

Comment: [@user31782](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3429430/user31782). It's very likely that `example.svg`, (mentioned in your comment), explicitly states `width` and `height` properties, hence no issue. If you inspect the `img` tag, the one with `media-object` class in your original gist, you can see it has no explicit css `width` property. [@Dekel](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5037551/dekel)'s answer is the best way to fix it. However, if you must link to the externally hosted `.svg`, and have no way to fix the svg asset you can inline `style="width: 64px; height:64px; float:left;"` to `img` tag.

Comment: Thanks @RobC. A vote-up on my answer will be appreciated :)

Comment: @RobC No. the example.svg will take it's default width without explicit `width` and `height` properties/attributes. E.g. see this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/b1wgrr8q/

Comment: @user31782, the `media-left` class has a `display: table-cell;`, which tells the browser to not occupy width unless there is content inside (that has defined-width).

Comment: @user31782, check this example: https://jsfiddle.net/b1wgrr8q/1/ I added a div (with 64px width) inside the `media-left` container. Once it's there - the SVG can occupy the width of the container and the image will be displayed.

Comment: @Dekel I understand this now as: A raster image will act like text and push the container element to contain it. The svg on the other hand will have intrinisic max-width = container's-width, that is it won't push the container to contain svg's default viewbox/canvas width.

Comment: This is what I wrote in my answer :) correct. The problem you has was with the `table-cell` (which makes browsers do weird things sometimes).

Comment: @Dekel yes thanks for explaining and clearing doubts in comments.

Comment: [@user31782](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3429430/user31782) I'm not sure I understand your 'No' comment. Using the same context/code as per your original gist you can, as previously mentioned, inline `style="width: 64px; height:64px; float:left;"` to the `img` tag. As per this [example](https://jsfiddle.net/b1wgrr8q/6/) to achieve the desired effect.

Comment: @RobC Sorry for my poor English. I meant that my example.svg in body tag simply doesn't have width and height explicitly set. I didn't mean we _can't_ get the svg show with explicit width and height. @_Dekel I am not accepting the answer now because I don't know about svg in detail. Also accepting answer would indicate that I have fully understood the reason. Aren't we over discussing it ? :-)

Comment: @user31782, this is exactly why we are not over discussing it. If something isn't clear - let me know so I can clarify it.

Comment: I don't think there is anything for you to explain more. It seems to be just how svg's work and I don't expect you to give a svg tutorial. If you give references to svg documentations which define this behavior then I will accept your answer. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Positions) doesn't mention about how svg width is affected by its container in html.